Unreal Engine - delay group of animations by 1 second
a) In Unreal Engine 5.4 I have 2,000 bats flying around. Unfortunately, they all flap their wings at the same time. How do I delay half of them by 1 second so they flap their wings at a different time?
b) Also, how do I get that effect of motion blur? Their wings seem to clean when they flap them.
Thank you so much for any help.
I tried finding the answer on youtube, but I am not successful.
